# Is there a way to send a session to routes.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

so I have a separate js file that does all of my routing. Is it possible to send a session to that routing? or do I have to do it all through my app.js?

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('./routes/routes.js');
const session = require('express-session'); //handles all of my routing
const PORT = 3000;
const app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'this is my secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true }
}));

app.post('/login', routes.login);
```

routes.js

```
var session;

exports.login = (req, res) => {
     session = req.session.user = {
          user_id : req.body.user_id,
          isAuthenticated : true,
     };
}
```

or do I have to do it like this?

```
var session;

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
      session = req.session.user = {
           user_id : req.body.user_id,
           isAuthenticated : true,
      };
})
```

I simply write my code like this because I only want my routes in my app.js because I think it's better to only have routes there else someone gives a valid reason to keep everything in my app.js.  This is the only way I know how to route my endpoints.  Any help or advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Attempting to assign `session` to a module scoped variable is wrong for a server.  Since your server can be used by multiple users, this will just cause different requests from different users to overwrite each other's data.  The ENTIRE point of a session object is so you don't have to do this.  You just use `req.session` in the request handler itself or if you really need to, you pass the session or some value from the sesison to some other function you are calling from your request handler.

Comment: If you show WHY you're trying to assign `session` this way, then we can help you with the proper way to solve that problem.

Comment: I'm just trying to use session to create a basic auth for my website that's all. But I understand that I would have to run things mainly through app.js correct? Instead of keeping my endpoints in app.js and putting the routes somewhere else.

Comment: You can put your routes anywhere you want.  Just only access the session in `req.session` - that will be available in any file you put your routes (because it's passed to every route).  Don't assign it to some other variable.  A session is NOT a server-wide variable.  It's specific to ONE request and only that request and requests from other users will have different sessions.  Can can't code your server pretending that there's only ever one session active.